# Usage of ShowComposeSmsMessageAsync

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'd like to send a text message using ShowComposeSmsMessageAsync (which shows the messaging app) and once the user tap the send button, I'd like the app goes to foreground again automatically.

Is it possible to avoid a user action to come back to the app?

Comment: It seems there is no method or button in message to let you launch to other app. So  when you jump to the message app, it can not  come back to your app.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking about :/